# a fraction containing a very small value is equal to Dirac's delta function

Tags: epsilon-delta, dirac-delta

When $\epsilon$ goes to infinite small value ($\epsilon\rightarrow 0$), how can I show $\sum_{k}\frac{\epsilon}{(E-E_k)^2+\epsilon^2}$ is equal to $\pi\sum_{k}\delta(E-E_k)$.

Comment: Do you know the definition of Dirac's $\delta$? I mean the real one, which has to do with integrals.

Comment: The minus sign should not be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distributions, like $\delta$, are formally defined by their behaviour on infinitely differentiable functions with compact support. Therefore we take $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and evaluate the following integral:
$$
\int \frac{\epsilon}{E^2+\epsilon^2} \phi(E) \, dE
= \{ E = \epsilon \hat{E} \}
= \int \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2 \hat{E}^2+\epsilon^2} \phi(\epsilon\hat{E}) \, \epsilon \, d\hat{E} \\
= \int \frac{1}{\hat{E}^2+1} \phi(\epsilon\hat{E}) \, d\hat{E}
\to \int \frac{1}{\hat{E}^2+1} \phi(0) \, d\hat{E}
= \int \frac{1}{\hat{E}^2+1} \, d\hat{E} \, \phi(0) \\
= \pi \phi(0)
= \int \pi \, \delta(E) \, \phi(E) \, dE.
$$
Thus,
$$
\frac{\epsilon}{E^2+\epsilon^2} = \pi \, \delta(E), \\
\frac{\epsilon}{(E-E_k)^2+\epsilon^2} = \pi \, \delta(E-E_k), \\
\sum_k \frac{\epsilon}{(E-E_k)^2+\epsilon^2} = \sum_k \pi \, \delta(E-E_k). \\
$$

Comment: Your solution is very interesting and you seems to be very intelligent!!!

Comment: Actually I was a bit sloppy here.